# extjs split button arrow click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extjs, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to click arrow on  extjs split button through selenium webdriver. I have tried multiple times but not getting any breakthrough. this is the link below where you will find split button. i just want somehow selenium click on arrow so that menu items get expand rest of work i will handle. any help is appreciated

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.SplitButton.html

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Simplest approach would be to use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('splitbutton'). You will get an array of all the splitbuttons, get the right one and call a method on that component.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, that split button is part of my project and i am writing selenium code like this driver.findElement(By.Id("options")).click();

Comment: if i execute Ext.ComponentQuery.query('splitbutton') on chrome console https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.SplitButton.html how do i click on arrow chrome console javascript command if i know i can execute inside selenium.

Comment: So AFTER you click the button RUN in this page you want to expand the options in the menu?

Comment: either through javascript command on console or native selenium command i want to click on arrow of split button, once i click on arrow a menu will popup with menu items

Comment: i expected to use executeScript - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [clickAt](https://javadoc.io/static/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.44.0/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/ClickAt.html) method to click on the right side of the button:

```java
driver.findElement(By.Id("options")).clickAt("60,10");
```

The correct values depend on the button size, just take about -10 pixels of the width and half the height.

Comment: clickAt() method is not available in 3.8.1 selenium-java, so i tried                                  int buttonWidth = optionbutton.getSize().width;
        int xOffset = buttonWidth/2 - 3;
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver());
        builder.moveToElement(optionbutton, xOffset, 0);
        builder.click();

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through executing extjs javascript command through selenium which will open/expand menu items.

```
window.c = Ext.getCmp('options')
c.showMenu()
```

Once all items expands, we can click on elements using selenium or through javascript.